# Terraform: how can I check if another resource is available

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a Terraform setup that looks basically like this:

```
Project
├──common
│  └─── cloudfront.tf
│  └─── lambda1.tf
│  └─── lambda2.tf
│
├──staging
│  └─── main.tf
│  └─── symlink to ../common/cloudfront.tf
│  └─── symlink to ../common/lambda2.tf
│
└──prod
   └─── main.tf
   └─── symlink to ../common/cloudfront.tf
   └─── symlink to ../common/lambda1.tf
   └─── symlink to ../common/lambda2.tf
```

So to be able to reuse the different files for staging and/or prod.

Problem I now have is, that in this example staging only has lambda2.tf but not lambda1.tf but the cloudfront.tf has to conditionally create a dynamic block based on whether or not the resource from lambda1.tf is "available" or not.

I tried something like this (with and without the `try()`):

```
dynamic "blockname" {
    for_each = try( aws_lambda_function.myname, null ) != null ? [1] : []
    # ...
}
```

but as it says in the docs:

> The try function will not catch errors relating to constructs that are probably invalid even before dynamic expression evaluation, such as a malformed reference or a reference to a top-level object that has not been declared

I don't want to add an extra variable to toggle the creation of the dynamic block.
Is there a way to achieve what I am trying?

Comment: So this is not going to be possible, but you can avoid this with some refactoring. Your `common` could become a declared module, or you could use Terraform CLI workspaces. Both would clean up your codebase, and allow you to proactively and not reactively declare the lambda for your infrastructure.

Comment: @Marcin I rewrote the whole thing to use custom modules and used variables + count to enable certain resources if I needed them

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create [custom data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) to query a pre-existance status of a resource. Otherwise, you can't do that in TF.